# VB.NET SQL: Getting multiple columns to go together as 1 DisplayMember in a ColumnBox?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a combobox created and a table where I have first and last name both as columns. I want my columnbox to list the names of the first and last names put together and I'm not sure how to progress. I tried changing my DisplayMember to "First Name" but that only displays the first name when I run the program, I want BOTH.

This code was automatically added to my .vb file when I changed the displaymember to first name only:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
```

Is there something I must add here? I'll stay here diligently until I get an answer and answer questions.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
ALSO
WHEN I Used a binding script to update my tables immediately, can I use a modified one to update the combobox immediately?

```
Private Sub BindGridSalespeople()
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Salespeople", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Show some sql code first

Comment: Why not make a column in your sql that is something like FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName and bind your combobox to that?

Comment: @SeanLange Because I have my sql table showing up on my form too and I can't have them both together, it has to be separate on the table that shows up on the form, and together on the combobox..

Comment: So add it as another column in your select statement. Unless there is a large number of rows the performance impact would be unnoticeable.

Comment: @SeanLange I followed your advice to add another column, now, where do I go from here? I'm new

Comment: Change the TextField of your combobox to your new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot add column to the `DataSource` used for filling `ComboBox` with values
Then add [`Computed Column`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188300.aspx) in your SQL Table

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
```

Then use new column for `DisplayMember` in the combobox

```
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

But I think adding column to the database only for UI purpose isn't best approach.
Exist much methods to add columns to the DataTable(Expression Column) if you using DataTable
Or adding column in the Select statement of SQL query
Or playing with properties of entities if you using Entities Framework

Comment: This is nice. So I have another question, how can I get it to immediately update once I add another entry for first and last name? Without shutting down the program and restarting it??

Comment: @ProjectCoder, if you mean update displayed values in the combobox if they was updated somewhere else, then you need to update DataSource which bounded to the combobox. Again: show a code how you filling combobox with data

Comment: I did it with the design mainly. Do you know how to open up the designer code? I used to, but I forgot now =|

Comment: When I got my tables to update automatically with the new table data, I used a binding method. Is it possible for me to use a similar method to update the combobox data immecdiately?

    Private Sub BindGridSalespeople()
        Dim constring As String = "server=NICOSQL06;database=AutoDealer_MatthewBuhr"
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Salespeople", con)

Comment: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

Comment: Fabio what do you mean show a code how I fill combobox with data? I just connected it to a database!

Comment: A View would probably be a better approach. Note you need to deal with null First or Last.